# forming a list of dictionary from a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a `list` in `python` whose sample data looks like this:

```
list_str = ['1. Option 1', '2. Option 2 ', '3. Option 3', '4. Option 4']
```

Now what I want to do is form a `list of dictionary` using items from this `list`. The output `list of dictionary` should look like this:

```
[
                        {
                            "text": "1. Option 1",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "2. Option 2",
                            "value": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "3. Option 3",
                            "value": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "4. Option 4",
                            "value": "4"
                        }

                    ]
```

Now I tried this as first step to form the `list of dictionary`:

```
list_of_dict = dict((x,y) for x,y in enumerate(list_str,1))
```

which produces this output, which is not the correct output but I am unable to modify it further to get the desired output:

```
{1: '1. Option 1 ', 2: '2. Option 2 ', 3: '3. Option 3 ', 4: 'Option 4 '}
```

How can I modify my code to get the correct desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
dictionaries = []

for x, y in enumerate(list_str, 1):
    dictionaries.append({'text': y, 
                         'value': str(x)
                        })
```

Or make it a one liner:

```
dictionaries = [{'text': y, 'value': str(x)} for x, y in enumerate(list_str, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
In [11]: [{'value':str(x),'text':y} for x,y in enumerate(list_str,1)]
Out[11]: 
[{'text': '1. Option 1', 'value': '1'},
 {'text': '2. Option 2 ', 'value': '2'},
 {'text': '3. Option 3', 'value': '3'},
 {'text': '4. Option 4', 'value': '4'}]
```

List comprehension will be the solution, But you have to specify the key and value in each iteration, then only it will assign properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this (one of many possibilities):

```
list_of_dict = [{'text': s, 'value': s.split('.')[0]} for s in list_str]
```